# Unable to identify the axios error I have in fetching data on React Native app

Tags: react-native, axios, fastify

I am having a trouble making an http request in my RN application.

**Metro:**
Metro waiting on exp://192.168.18.27:19000

**Server:**

```
import Fastify from 'fastify'
import cors from '@fastify/cors'
import { appRoutes } from './routes'

const app = Fastify()
app.register(cors)
app.register(appRoutes)

app
  .listen({
    port: 3333,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('HTTP Server running')
  })
```

**Axios config in app**

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://192.168.18.27:3333',
})
```

**Component function fetching the data**

```
 async function fetchData() {
    try {
      setLoading(true)
      const response = await api.get('/summaryTable')
      console.log('response', response)
      setSummary(response.data)
      console.log('response', response)
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert('Ops', 'Não foi possível carregar o sumário de hábitos.')
      console.log(error)
    } finally {
      setLoading(false)
    }
  }

  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      fetchData()
    }, [])
  )
```

**Error expo console:**
LOG  [AxiosError: Network Error]

The call is working on postman, on the browser, on the web version, but doesn't work on mobile.

Does anyone have an idea what's it about?

Thanks!

I tryed to use fetch, tested fetch using the randomuser api and it worked properly, but I can't make it work in anyway.

EDIT
Tryed to add host to app.listen:

```
import Fastify from 'fastify'
import cors from '@fastify/cors'
import { appRoutes } from './routes'

const app = Fastify()
app.register(cors)
app.register(appRoutes)

app
  .listen({
    port: 3333,
    host: '0.0.0.0', (also tryed with my IP address)
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('HTTP Server running')
  })
```

And now have the following answer:
LOG  response {"_bodyBlob": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "0cccbd6f-30fa-4d62-bc04-2d41d5c00140", "offset": 0, "size": 632}}, "_bodyInit": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "0cccbd6f-30fa-4d62-bc04-2d41d5c00140", "offset": 0, "size": 632}}, "bodyUsed": false, "headers": {"map": {"access-control-allow-origin": "*", "connection": "keep-alive", "content-length": "632", "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8", "date": "Wed, 29 Mar 2023 19:32:56 GMT", "keep-alive": "timeout=72", "vary": "Origin"}}, "ok": true, "status": 200, "statusText": "", "type": "default", "url": "http://192.168.18.27:3333/summary"}
ERROR  There was a problem sending log messages to your development environment [PrettyFormatPluginError: value.hasOwnProperty is not a function. (In 'value.hasOwnProperty('tag')', 'value.hasOwnProperty' is undefined)]

Comment: Did you try to add the host parameter to the app.listen method? It should be 0.0.0.0

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon yes, but I have a different error now.  ERROR  There was a problem sending log messages to your development environment [PrettyFormatPluginError: value.hasOwnProperty is not a function. (In 'value.hasOwnProperty('tag')', 'value.hasOwnProperty' is undefined)]

Comment: No, you need 0.0.0.0 on the server and `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` on the client - anyway, is the server logging something? does the client reach the server now? Is the `hasOwnProperty` function executed in the server's routes?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon Thanks. I had to change both the server and the client using my ip address (metro shows it). Thanks for the help!!